# mongodb collection inserting record is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While inserting the collection in mongo db working with nodejs and mongoose, defined two files

**The Model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stack1');


var stackSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var tagData = new Schema(
{
    tag  : String,
    data :[viewData]
}
    )
var viewData = new Schema({
    view     : String,
    date      : Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', tagData);
```

**The View.js**

```
var Tag =  require('./Model');

var view =({
    "view" : "700",
    "date" : "2001/1/20"

});

var tag = new Tag(
            {"tag" : "java"}


    );


tag.data.push(view);
//console.log(tag)
tag.save(function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Success!');

});
```

While executing the above code i can see the sucess message in the console

```
bash $ node view.js 
Success!
```

When i query the mongodb collections it return nothing

```
> db.stack1.find()
```

**What wrong i'm doing and how can i correct it**

Comment: if you execute query in mongodb console then you should to change the database `use stack1`, and after this you have access to `tag` collection `db.Tag.find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `find` query is looking in the `stack1` collection of the default database in the shell.

To query the contents of the `tags` collection in the `stack1` database that you're targeting with your code:

```
> use stack1
> db.tags.find()
```